# Taking first byte of the length of a string

Tags: php, ruby, byte, strlen, chr

I've started learning Ruby and I am stuck, I've tried many things but can't solve the problem.

I've got this code in PHP:

```
chr(strlen("root") & 0xFF);
chr(strlen("root") >> 8 & 0xFF);
```

And I need to change it to ruby.

Ruby's `chr` function does not allow me to do `>> 8 & 0xFF` or just `& 0xFF`, I don't know why.

I also don't know what those functions are, but I'm sure I need them to get my code to work.

If anyone can help me, explaining and giving me the right function would be great, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if I understood your question properly but, you can take the bytes of your string like this

```
string.bytes
```

and you will have an array with each byte. And, to get the char of any of that bytes, you can use

```
byte.chr
```

For example:

```
bytes_array = "I want a byte".bytes
=> [73, 32, 119, 97, 110, 116, 32, 97, 32, 98, 121, 116, 101]
```

And, to take the first byte back to char,

```
bytes_array[0].char
=> "I"
```

If you want the chars from the first 4 bytes, for example, you could do this:

```
string = ""
bytes_array[0..3].each do |b|
  string << b.chr
end
```

You will have the string

```
=> "I wa"
```

I hope have helped in something.